# AngularJS and CSS transition

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions

I have an AngularJS 1.2.9 app. My task is to introduce a CSS transition on this element:

```
<div class="search input container" x-ng-class="{'full screen': initial, 'on top': !initial}">
```

when a class changes from 'full screen' to 'on top'. CSS transition works well in Chrome Canary when I try it outside of the Angular app ([code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXBXN/2/)), but doesn't work in our app. Any ideas why the transition doesn't work when AngularJS is adding/removing classes? When I toggle the classes manually from a web inspector, it works. Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

P.S. Works only in Chrome Canary ATM, but that is ok for me.

Comment: Can you add more detail about how is `initial` handled?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I made it work be doing a small refactoring. Basically instead to toggling 4 CSS classes ('full screen' into 'on top') I'm using one CSS class ('fullscreen'). I don't understand what was the problem before and how my change fixed the issue. And I would like to understand.

New html code is:

```
<div class="search input container" x-ng-class="{'fullscreen': initial}">
```

And LESS:

```
&.input.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 10rem;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;

  &.fullscreen {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```